# PHP - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql

I've been pulling my hair out on this MySQL query.

Let's say I have this:

```
    $add = "INSERT INTO books (title) VALUES(?)";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($add)) {

        $arr = array($title);

        foreach ($arr as $value) {
            echo var_dump($value);
        }

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
```

With that `foreach` -> `var_dump` :

```
string 'Medieval Times (History)' (length=24)
int 1422843281
int 1420844341
string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
string 'MY_EMAIL@gmail.com' (length=22)
string '' (length=0)
int 1420844805
int 6
int 3
int 1
int 0
int 0
int 1
int 1
int 1
int 1
```

Well, it stops when it hits this line and I get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\books\dashboard.php on line 386`

With line 386: `$stmt->bind_param ...`

So, I know I am importing 16 variables yet ... I get this error. Argh.

Comment: Maybe your MySQLi query failed?

Comment: It's better to `var_dump($stmt);`

Comment: Also, isn't `state` a reserved word?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Almost, `SQLSTATE` is one

Comment: @Rizier123 It's just that MySQL has so many keywords that it's hard to memorize all.

Comment: Btw, use `var_dump($mysqli->error);` and tell us the result

Comment: All the param/column names match up except the last. Are they both correct? `imported`/`$importedVal`

Comment: @sectus, I did that and I got `boolean true`

Comment: @DanF, are you sure that $mysqli is a `mysqli` object? [Prepare](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) does not return true. Try to `var_dump($mysqli)`

Comment: @Darren `state` is not a reserved word in MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html Your link states `The list below represents a combination of the following sources of SQL reserved words: ANSI SQL 92, ANSI SQL 99, ANSI SQL 2003, MySQL 3.23.x, MySQL 4.x, MySQL 5.x, PostGreSQL 8.1, MS SQL Server 2000, MS ODBC, Oracle 10.2` so it is in one of the other listed, just not MySQL

Comment: @Sean Touche, I thought it was the most recent doc I linked, but it was last updated 2010. You get 15 cookies !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL\DR

Your query is failing to `prepare()`. You need to figure out where, how and why. Look at the last code block of this answer and let us know what the error is.

---

<s>I'll start with the query. You're trying to access a MySQL reserved word <sup>*[Source (See #684)](https://www.drupal.org/node/141051)*</sup>. You need to wrap those in backticks like this:</s>

```
$add = "INSERT INTO books (title, edited, created, ip,".
    " email_to, twitter, last_taken, questions_total, responses, ".
    "show_progress, need_correct, go_back, state, send_stats, ".
    "show_number, imported) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ".
    "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Now, you're instantiating the variable `$stmt` within the `if` block but then trying to bind it outside of that block. You'll need to change this:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($add)) {
....
}
$stmt->bind_param(....);
```

To this:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($add)) {
....
$stmt->bind_param(....);
}
```

Also, make sure your query is actually preparing correctly:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($add)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("siisssiiiiiiiiii", $title, $edited, $created, $ip, $email_to, $twitter, $last_taken, $questions_total, $responses, $show_progress, $need_correct, $go_back, $state, $send_stats, $show_number, $importedVal);

    // execute it and all...
} else {
    die("Errormessage: ". $mysqli->error);
}
```

Then let us know what turns up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$stmt->bind_param(array("siisssiiiiiiiiii", $title, $edited, $created, $ip, $email_to, $twitter, $last_taken, $questions_total, $responses, $show_progress, $need_correct, $go_back, $state, $send_stats, $show_number, $importedVal));
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: try this

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($add)) {

    $stmt->bind_param($arr);
}
else {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: There's actually 16 in the query and the binds.

Comment: Where is the OP's 17? I only count 16.

Comment: I usually bind all parameters and not some. The error is indicating that the statement fails to prepare, so the statement need to be checked for validation anyways as you indicated in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Two things maybe.

1. Is `$mysqli` out of scope? Other words, are you using `$mysqli` in a function but not passed to that function or it's not been declared global in that function?
2. In your table, is any of the columns of `INT` not an `INT`? could any of them be a `tinyint`,`smallint`, or `mediumint`? Then your values are too big.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your prepared statement because of an error in your SQL. As you have underscores in your field names, I almost guarantee that the problem is the `prepare` is throwing a wobbly over you not wrapping them in ` marks (I forget the actual name of the *flicky apostrophe*). You therefore need;

```
$add = "INSERT INTO books (title, edited, created, ip,".
  " `email_to`, `twitter`, `last_taken`, `questions_total`, `responses`, ".
  "`show_progress`, `need_correct`, `go_back`, `state`, `send_stats`, ".
  "`show_number`, `imported`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ".
  "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

I have wrapped all the fields with the marks as it is best practice, but in reality it's the special character that causes the problem in my experience.

Hope this helps.